# Fresh install - Linux newbie - when i try to open displays in system settings it just closes?

Tags: release-freya, settings

this is my first Linux OS,
installed alongside windows 10 on my SSD and its fine, though whenever i try to go to displays to edit my resolution and my other monitors ( it just duplicates them at the moment) the app closes and i get a system settings has closed unexpectedly?

I apologize if my info provided is not very detailed if anything else is needed please feel free to say, thank you in advance guys ( this is probably a really basic error aha )

Comment: It would help if you could open up the terminal and type in `switchboard`. Once you do that, you'll see the System Settings. After that, click on the `Displays`. If it crashes, you'll see the error log in your terminal. After that, edit your question and paste the errors you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed sorry! reinstalled switchboard and rebooted and it seemed to be fixed